# import databricks.koalas as ks :

Tags: api, pyspark, databricks

**Hola gente;
Tengo este problema; al momento de importar databricks.koalas me sale este error: Estoy intentando importar la librería de databricks.koalas para hacer transformaciones de pandas a spark; sin embargo me sale el siguiente error**

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 3
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 import numpy as np
----> 3 import databricks.koalas as ks
File ~\anaconda1\Lib\site-packages\databricks\koalas\__init__.py:74
     66     raise RuntimeError(
     67         "Please explicitly unset 'ARROW_PRE_0_15_IPC_FORMAT' environment variable in both "
     68         "driver and executor sides. It is required to set this environment variable only "
     69         "when you use pyarrow>=0.15 and pyspark<3.0."
     70     )
     73 from databricks.koalas.frame import DataFrame
---> 74 from databricks.koalas.indexes import Index, MultiIndex
     75 from databricks.koalas.series import Series
     76 from databricks.koalas.typedef import pandas_wraps
File ~\anaconda1\Lib\site-packages\databricks\koalas\indexes.py:51
     49 from databricks.koalas.frame import DataFrame
     50 from databricks.koalas.missing.indexes import _MissingPandasLikeIndex, _MissingPandasLikeMultiIndex
---> 51 from databricks.koalas.series import Series, _col
     52 from databricks.koalas.utils import (
     53     compare_allow_null,
     54     compare_disallow_null,
   (...)
     61     validate_bool_kwarg,
     62 )
     63 from databricks.koalas.internal import _InternalFrame, NATURAL_ORDER_COLUMN_NAME
File ~\anaconda1\Lib\site-packages\databricks\koalas\series.py:22
     20 import re
     21 import inspect
---> 22 from collections import Iterable, OrderedDict
     23 from functools import partial, wraps, reduce
     24 from typing import Any, Generic, List, Optional, Tuple, TypeVar, Union
ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterable' from 'collections'
```

**Alguien sabe como corregirlo? Gracias!**

Comment: What version of Spark (or Databricks Runtime) is used? Also, what is the Python version?

Comment: Version of Spark: 3.4.1

Comment: Versión of Python: Python 3.11.3

Comment: in 3.4.1 you need to use Pandas on Spark, not Koalas: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/index.html